# I cant use do until and if with Form.visible control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I was trying to create a Form using Do Until. The thing is when ı run this code I get an exception : "System.InvalidCastException".
So here is the code Im trying to run:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim x As Boolean = False
    Do Until x
        If Form2.Visible = False & Form3.Visible = False & Form4.Visible = False Then
            x = True
        End If
    Loop
End
End Sub
```

Also as an explanation of what I'm trying to do: When form2,form3 and form4 is NOT visible The Program will End

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB.NET the logical operator to use is **And** or better **AndAlso**

```
If Form2.Visible = False AndAlso 
   Form3.Visible = False AndAlso 
   Form4.Visible = False Then
   x = True
End if
```

AndAlso is better because if the left side of the operator is false then it breaks immediately the test without evaluating the rest of the line

Of course, keep in mind that this loop is an infinite loop if any of these forms is visible. It will continue to run ad infinitum and you cannot do anything to the other forms to allow it to exit. This will effectively crush your UI.
At least you need to add an Application.DoEvents here to allow some other action to happen inside that loop.